# How to provide back navigation in a sub-flow with activities

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack

I have Activities A, B, C which between the user can navigate.

Activity B also provides a sub-flow like (B1, B2, B3). When the user completes the subflow, he is sent back to B with some data.

What intent flags or launch modes should I use to provide back navigation between A - B - C, and between B1 - B2 - B3. But also clear/finish this sub flow when returning to B with some data passed in the intent?

I have tried adding `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` & `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` to the sub activities (B1, B2, B3) but that didn't work.

[image: visual explanation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I managed to get the desired result by doing the following. In Activity B, I created 2 methods to start the activity

```
class ActivityB : AppCompatActivity() {

    fun startFromActivityA(context: Context) {
        val intent = Intent(context, ActivityB::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }

    fun startFromActivityB2(context: Context, intentData: IntentData) {
        val intent = Intent(context, ActivityB::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(INTENT_DATA, intentData)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

So when I enter the subflow and i want to finish the subflow, I would call `startFromActivityB2`. It would clear the whole subflow and still provide back navigation to Activity A

Answer (score 0):

in your activity B2:

```
  public void finish(){
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("KEY_NAVIGATION", "B");
        Intent intent = new Intent(B2.this, A.class);
        intent.putExtra("EXTRA", bundle);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

in your Activity A:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        component.inject(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getIntent().hasExtra("EXTRA")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        // do your logic
    }
```

with this way, you can back to A from B after navigate from B2

Hope this helps

Comment: if you want back to A from B after navigate from B2, I will update my answer

Comment: I updated my answer, if you have any question, ready to help you !

Answer (score 0):

You could use chained `onActivityResult` calls, so rather than going from B2 around to B, you go automatically backwards through the same chain (B2->B1->B) calling `finish()` as you go to remove the chain from the back stack. This way you can still use the back button as expected while at B1 or B2, but pressing Back once you go A->B->B1->B2->B would bring you back to A, not to B2.

This will work no matter how many activities you had visited before B (for example, if you went from Aa->Ab->Ac->B then through the B->B1->B2->B loop, you could then still go back through B->Ac->Ab->Aa).

```
public class ActivityB extends AppCompatActivity {

  private static final int LAUNCH_B1 = 11;

  void launch_subloop() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityB1.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, LAUNCH_B1);
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if( resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == LAUNCH_B1) {
      // do stuff upon loop completion
    }
  }
}

public class ActivityB1 extends AppCompatActivity {
  private static final int LAUNCH_B2 = 12;

  void go_to_next_step() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB2.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, LAUNCH_B2);
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if( resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == LAUNCH_B2) {
      // This will finish B1 and bring us back to B, with B1 and B2 now 
      // removed from the back stack
      setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
      finish();
    }
  }
}

public class ActivityB2 extends AppCompatActivity {

  void finish_subloop() {
    // when you finish, this should go back through the 
    // activities and finish B1 and B2, so if you go on from B to C, you can
    // still go back from C -> B -> A
    // This will bring us back to B1 and finish B2 (remove from back stack)
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    finish();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make in manifest of Activity B:

```
launchMode = “singleTask”
```

So after Activity B2 you can *startActivity("intent for activity b2 with putting some data in this intent")* and handle your intent in *onNewIntent()* in Activity B

If Actvities B, B1, B2 is the same activities, why not just to make it with fragments?

You can also make same thing without lunchMode by flags:

from Activity A

```
startActivity("intent for activity b with putting some data in this intent", Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
```

in Activity B

```
startActivity("intent for activity B with data (if needs)", Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)
```

in Activity B1

```
startActivity("intent for activity B with data (if needs)", Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)
```

in Activity B2

```
startActivity("intent for activity B with data (if needs)", Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
```